# How would one go about 'chain' piping more than 2 pipes in C++? Currently I am getting the Bad file descriptor error from Bash on the second command

Tags: c++, bash, pipe, fork

To expand on this, by chain piping I am referring to when I have 3 separate processes:
process 1 writes to process 2,
process 2 reads from process 1 and writes to process 3,
process 3 reads from process 2 and then finishes.

I am specifically trying to handle complex commands in a C++ written bash shell. So I would be using this to execute a set of commands like this that all communicate with each other:

ls | sort | grep "exit"

where process 1 is executing ls and its stdout is written to process 2 through a pipe, etc.

I already am writing code to solve this for a project and was just wondering if my approach is correct, as right now when just doing a 2 command call of ls | grep "exit" I am getting the bash error "grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor"

```
//Block for when the userInput is a complex command
            else{
                if (debug)
                    printf("Complex command: %s\n", userInput.c_str());

                vector<char*> commandsVect = splitCString(const_cast<char*>(userInput.c_str()), const_cast<char*>( delimVertPipe.c_str()));
                if (debug)
                    printVect(commandsVect);

                if (pipe(fileDescriptor) == -1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed for command %s\n", userInput.c_str());
                    return 1;
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < commandsVect.size(); ++i) {
                    vector<char*> tokens = splitCString(const_cast<char*>(commandsVect[i]), const_cast<char*>( delimSpace.c_str()));
                    printf("Commands vect size is %ld\n", commandsVect.size());
                    printf("Parsing command \'%s\'\n", commandsVect[i]);
                    if (debug) {
                        printVect(tokens);
                    }

                    procID = fork();
                    //Block for the first command
                    if (i == 0){
                        if (procID < 0){
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fork number %d in the complex command \'%s\' failed\n", i+1, userInput.c_str());
                            return 1;
                        }
                        //Child process
                        else if (procID == 0){

                            //close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);
                            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                            //Links the write end of the pipe to the STDOUT
                            dup2(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END], 1);

                            close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);
                            close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);

                            tokens.push_back(nullptr); //execvp() arg array needs a NULL pointer at the end
                            if ( execvp(tokens[0], tokens.data()) < 0 ) {
                                fprintf( stderr, "execvp() call failed for the command \'%s\' inside the input string \'%s\'\n", commandsVect[i], userInput.c_str() );
                                return 1;
                            }
                            exit(1);

                        }
                        //Parent process
                        else{
                            close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);
                            close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);
                            wait(NULL);
                        }
                    }
                    //Block for the very last command, which will pipe input from the previous
                    else if (i == commandsVect.size() - 1){
                        if (procID < 0){
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fork number %d in the complex command \'%s\' failed\n", i+1, userInput.c_str());
                            return 1;
                        }
                            //Child process
                        else if (procID == 0){
                            //close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);
                            close(STDIN_FILENO);
                            //Links the read end of the pipe to the STDIN
                            dup2(fileDescriptor[READ_END], 0);

                            close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);
                            close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);

                            tokens.push_back(nullptr); //execvp() arg array needs a NULL pointer at the end
                            if ( execvp(tokens[0], tokens.data()) < 0 ) {
                                fprintf( stderr, "execvp() call failed for the command \'%s\' inside the input string \'%s\'\n", commandsVect[i], userInput.c_str() );
                                return 1;
                            }
                            exit(1);
                        }
                            //Parent process
                        else{
                            close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);
                            close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);
                            wait(NULL);
                        }
                    }
                    //To note for StackOverflow, this block of code is never executed since I am only ever calling a 2 chained command like ls|grep "exit"
                    //Block for the middle commands. (Will pipe input from previous, and output to the next)
                    else{
                        printf("GOING THROUGH BAD CODE");
                        continue;
                        if (procID < 0){
                            fprintf(stderr, "Fork number %d in the complex command \'%s\' failed\n", i+1, userInput.c_str());
                            return 1;
                        }
                            //Child process
                        else if (procID == 0){
                            exit(1);
                        }
                            //Parent process
                        else{
                            wait(NULL);
                        }
                    }
                }
                close(fileDescriptor[READ_END]);
                close(fileDescriptor[WRITE_END]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible with your larger application, but you could simplify things by letting the shell manage the pipes. Write P1 (process one), P2, and P3 as three separate executables. In stead of doing IO on pipes, each program could read from stdin and write to stdout. Simple. To execute - let bash or whatever shell you use glue the three together by calling them as...

```
$P1 | P2 | P3;
```

Under the hood, your shell is doing pretty much what you're doing in C++ (only successfully ). It creates a pipe for P1, which it passes to exec as stdin to launch P1 after forking. It creates an input and output pipe for P2, and binds it stdin and stdout as appropriate in the same way - passed into exec when launching P2 after the fork. P3 gets only a stdin pipe and its stdout stream goes right to the console as normal. It's not quite as sexy as doing it all in C++, but it's very robust - pretty much guaranteed to work.